# ML: Connecting trained model to best inputs to generate events

Tags: machine-learning, inference

I have target vector that encompasses 50 imbalanced classes.

I have a feature matrix that encompasses 25 different features.

I have a trained tree model and have limited test set data.

What I want to do is:

- For every y-class, generate a top-k set of input data such that if I used that exact set, the model would yield predicted probabilities for each set.

This seems like hyperparameter tuning for data rather than model parameters. Is there a particular phrase or algorithm associated with this endeavor? Alternatively -- your recommendation!

My goal is to derive the most likely feature combinations (lets say top 3) that generate class y==1, and the next most likely feature combinations that generate class y==2, and so on. I am curious about the situation where I have no new test data, but with the goal that, I would eventually use the most likely feature combinations to generate new events of y==1 with probability k, and new events of y==2 with probability k, and so on.

I am also curious about the situation where I do have lots of test data -- do I simply open up the test data, group by each class y, and get the mode for each input feature?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "generate a top-k set of input data such that if I used that exact set, the model would judge that I am n% likely to yield class y of interest"? I assume n is given. Is a "top-k set" a set of k inputs ranked by how close they are to the n% for y? Does "use that exact set" mean training on it? And can this set be a subset of your sample, or does it have to be unobserved? Elaborating on the goal/motivation of this analysis will also help.

Comment: Some comments added! It would be useful to see strategies for situations against subset of my sample data as well as unobserved.

Comment: Thank you for the additional comments. Can you describe the goal/motivation at an even higher level? For example, is the goal to characterize the classes through features / develop profiles for each class? (Also it looks like the bullet point in the post needs some rewording.)

Comment: The goal/motivation is that: each of the input features are a tunable parameter in real life, but its unclear to the person in control of those parameters what values to select to generate outcomes of interest. So if x1 == 0, x2 == 3, x3==25, x4==0, and so on, after a while, the user doesn't quite know what set of inputs will generate what sort of outcome y. And, is there a set of inputs k1 that does better at generating class 1 than another set of inputs k2? If so, what are the values for k1 / how do we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be highly related to the notion of adversarial attack.

An adversarial example is an input $x$ to the network which has been specifically designed to yield output $\hat{y}$ with a high confidence level. However, this output $\hat{y}$ may be different from the ground-truth class $y$. The classical example of an adversarial example is an image of a panda (as labelled by a human user) to which an infinitesimal perturbation is applied. The end result will be classified as a gibbon by the network with a very high level of confidence (Figure 1 in this classical paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572.pdf).

The point is that it is indeed possible to engineer samples which will yield a certain output with a very high confidence, using e.g. the following perturbation derived in page 3 of the paper mentioned above:
$$
\eta = \epsilon \textbf{sign}(\nabla_x J(\theta,x,y))
$$
As you nicely mentioned, this is similar to optimization over the features of the data rather than over the parameters of the model (see that the gradient is computed over $x$ above). The problem is that these samples, which were optimized to yield $\hat{y}$, may not have anything in common with what you would intuitively expect from archetypes from class $\hat{y}$: the right most image in Figure 1 generates the expected output of the network, but does not look like a gibbon at all.

Another classical paper on adversarial examples is this one, in which the authors discuss the possibility to extend adversarial attacks to humans and identify which features in the image are most likely to be modified: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/file/8562ae5e286544710b2e7ebe9858833b-Paper.pdf